# Cannot activate transaction for junit test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, transactions

I want to test a transactional method. I added the @transactional over test method but I got an exception `IllegalStateException: Failed to retrieve PlatformTransactionManager for @Transactional test`. I don't know how to activate the transaction. I tried to add `TestTransaction.start()` in the first line of the test body but it throws an exception that the transaction is not active. I don't know what's wrong with my test.
If I remove classes in @SpringbootTest the test randomly throws `NoSuchBeanException` for my repositories.
My test method:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.H2)
class PersistenceHelperTest {

    @Autowired
    private ReturnRepository returnRepository;
    @SpyBean
    private PersistenceHelper persistenceHelper;


 @Test
void removeFromDbOnWriteExceptionForNotWritableFile(@TempDir Path tempDir) {
    Path testFile = tempDir.resolve("testFile.txt");


     try {
            String content = "This is a test";
            testFile.toFile().createNewFile();
            boolean writable = testFile.toFile().setWritable(false);

            assertTrue("File should not be writable", writable);
            persistenceHelper.saveToFileAndDB(content.getBytes(), testFile.toFile().getAbsolutePath(), returnFile, returnRepository);
            fail();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           assertTrue("Should be instance of IOException", e instanceof IOException);
           assertTrue("Should exists", Files.exists(testFile));
           assertSame(0, returnRepository.findAll().size());
        }
}
```

The class under the test:

@Component
public class PersistenceHelper {

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = {IOException.class}, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public <T extends BaseEntity> void saveToFileAndDB(byte[] fileContent, String fileAbsolutePath, T entity, JpaRepository<T, Long> jpaRepository) throws IOException {

    FileTransactionListener transactionListener = new FileTransactionListener(new FileDeleter(), fileAbsolutePath);
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(transactionListener);
     jpaRepository.save(entity);
        FileUtil.writeToFile(fileAbsolutePath, fileContent);
    }
}
```

my Springboot class:

```
  @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableJpaRepositories("packageAddress")
    public class MyApplication {
```

Comment: Instead of marking test case as ` @Transactional`, you should simply try to create such a scenario in test case where method under test throws 'IOException' and you can assert whether the transaction got rolled back,

Comment: @Smile: Thank you for your answer. I changed the test method and update the codes. Now when I run the test class with the three test methods, this method is not rolled back and in another test, the object is committed neither. but calling the test method individually, the transaction is rolled back, and the test passed. What is wrong with my test now? thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: When you say '3 test methods', do you mean 3 assert statements? Because I can only see 1 test method. Also, `Assertions.assertThrows` is better than writing try catch in the junit.